# Spring Boot Property value prefixing when trying to invoke using @Value

Tags: spring-boot

At property applicaiton.yml file I have few properties like below

Service
uri
dean: /myproj/mywork/doit
ream: /thedate/isit/done

When I am using @Value to get above values. During start of the application it showing I/O error and value of above coming as /null/myproj/mywork/doit

Just FYI above value is part of uri which I am using to invoke another service.

I tried to use

String UriComponentsBuilder.fromUriString(dean)

to get rid of /null but not working.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

you can try to define as string in  application.yaml, code snippet like below

```
default_mq: "amqp://xxxxxxx"
```

```java
@Value("${default_mq:amqp://xxxxxxx}")
String default_mq
```

the meaning behind `:` is that when spring get the default_mq from environment is not exists or null , it would take the default value which is behind `:`